# how to make for loop faster in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following method that takes forever:

```
def UuserEmailAgentIdD(self, CemailToIdD, MUuserWithAgentD):
    """return a dict of user_email:agent:id - only users with agents
       Argumetns:
                CemailToIdD:        dict of all user emails : ids
                MUuserWithAgentD:   dict of pure user ID:agent_id"""
    return_dict = {}
    user_ids = MUuserWithAgentD.keys() 
    for user_email in CemailToIdD:
        if CemailToIdD[user_email] in user_ids: 
            return_dict[user_email] = MUuserWithAgentD[CemailToIdD[user_email]]
    return return_dict
```

How do I speed this up?

Comment: It looks like you are performing a join. Have you tried libraries suited for this task?

Comment: I'd suggest you use the profiler to see what's taking all the time before you do anything.  Also let's you measure the time so you know emperically when you've improved the execution time.

Comment: How about this: `{user:{id:MUuserWithAgentD[id]} for user, id in CemailToIdD.items() if id in MUuserWithAgentD.keys()}` This doesnt change the logic but it does use list/dictionary comprehension which is optimized in python.

Comment: **Never, ever, ever** do `thing in somedict.keys()`. You are performing a slow list search instead of a fast hash lookup.

Comment: All good stuff!  Thanks!  @user2357112 what is an alternative?

Comment: You know how you're already doing `for user_email in CemailToIdD` without calling `keys`? You can test for key presence the same way, with `thing in d` instead of `thing in d.keys()`, and it'll do a hash lookup.

Comment: @user2357112 yup.  that did the trick.

Comment: @congusbongus are their libraries for python that do this sort of thing for mongodb?